# how to make a request several times without hard refresh with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I send a request via ajax to delete a file. The first time , ajax handles the request, but the second time not anymorte. i got a "hard refresh"

This is my code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['deletefile'])) {

        // if is directory -> remove dir
        if(is_dir($_POST['deletefile'])){

        removeDirectory($_POST['deletefile']);      
        exit;

        }
        // else (must be a file) -> unlink file
        else {

        unlink($_POST['deletefile']);
        exit;
        }

}
?>
<div class="myFiles">
 <form class="sfmform" method="post" action="">
        <input type="hidden" name="deletefile" value="<?php echo $dir.'/'.$file; ?>" />
        <input type="submit" class="sfmdelete"  name="delete" value=" " />
 </form> 
 <script>
  $(".sfmform").on('submit',(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
            url: "",
            type: "POST",
            data:  new FormData(this),

            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(response)
            {           
            $('.myFiles').load(document.URL +  ' .myFiles');
            },

       });

    }));
 </script>

 </div> <!-- END myFiles -->
```

To see immediately when i file has been deleted, i use this line
`$('.myFiles').load(document.URL +  ' .myFiles');`

The first delete request goes fine, but the second: he makes a hard refresh and dies in the php loop. I was hoping that after the `exit` in the php the line `$('.myFiles').load(document.URL +  ' .myFiles');` was executing but the second time it loads not the `<div class="myFiles>` anymore.

How can i make this work properly?

Even when i put the js in the ready handler, it does not work!
The reason why i use an `exit` in the php: otherwise the `<div class="myFiles">` appears 2 times under each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You changed the `html` of `.myFiles` so everything in it in the second time is dynamically generated . so you need [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements) .. change

```
$(".sfmform").on('submit',(function(e) {
```

to

```
$(document).on('submit' , ".sfmform" , (function(e) {
```

**Note:** *for me* its not a good practice to use `$.ajax` with the same file `url:` better *for me* to make a separate file

Comment: Perfect solution! It works fine now! I am gonna read you link about event binding. I really did get stuck on this problem. Thnx

Comment: You're totally Welcome @JackMaessen .. Have a nice day :-)